# How to log out showing the proper status?

Tags: javascript

I have a members site. Every web page's header bar will have the following 2 options depending the user is logged in or not:

Option 1) if the user is logged in, it will have the following 2 links:

"user12345"
"logout"

Option 2) if the user is log out, above 2 links will become:

"login"
"register"

The page has some Javascript code which will check a user cookie. If the user cookie exists, if will display option 1), otherwise option 2). There is no problem with the Javascript. It shows above options correctly.

Here's the problem. I use a server side script (perl) to do the "logout" function. The script will delete the cookie and re-direct back to the original page. I am hoping the page will show option 2), but it doesn't. It still shows option 1). The page needs to be refreshed to show option 2). This is confusing because users have clicked the logout link, yet when they return to the page, they still see their usernames there. They need to refresh the web browser in order to see that they have logged out.

Option 2) should show on the page upon clicking the "logout" link. But I simply have no idea how to get this done successfully.

Please provide your expertise to fix this problem.

Comment: I hope your server-side code is signing the cookie or something so someone can't just edit the cookie to be logged in as a different user.

Comment: What JavaScript event are you using to trigger the JS code that check's the user's cookie?

Answer (score 1):

First, I would suggest breaking the problem down so that you can test the logout functionality separate from the page redirect.

- Modify your Perl script so logout doesn't redirect.
- Login and then click logout.
- Use a Chrome or Firefox extension that lets you view cookies.  Verify that the cookie has been deleted.

If everything checks out here, I would suggest that you then reconnect the redirect and repeat the above steps:

- When your page redirects and you don't see the login | register buttons, check to see if the cookie was deleted, if the cookie appears, then there may be something being cached in the code after the redirect.

As an alternative, you could use the document.referrer to capture your logout URL in your JavaScript code and also use this to determine if you should show the login | register buttons.  For instance:

```
if(document.referrer = "/logout" || /* existing check of cookie goes here */) {
    // show login | register
} else {
    // show username, etc.
}
```

If possible, the best solution usability-wise would be to turn your logout url into an AJAX call so you don't need to reload the page. This would be better than the above solution because you could check the response object to determine if the logout operation was a success. If so, you could then dynamically replace the header bar with the correct text.

An AJAX example, using [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), is as follows:

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: '/logout',
    success: function(data) {
        if(data.logout == true) {
            // user is logged out
        }
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        /* problem with logout */
    }
});
```

Your perl logout script will need to return a JSON object as a String, if successful:

```
{"logout":true}
```

There are other ways of making AJAX calls and transferring data to/from the server, and you can find those examples doing a search on Stackoverflow for "AJAX".

Comment: Everything checks ok as you suggested. I'm new to using AJAX. Kindly give me an example of your AJAX call.

Comment: I've shown the javacript. Kindly show me more details how to incorporate your AJAX call together with my javacript.

Answer (score 0):

> BlockquoteFirst, I would suggest breaking the problem down so that you can test the logout functionality separate from the page redirect...

I've fixed the problem without the use of AJAX call.